# Get total value when input a quantity in form control in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray

I tried to get total value each item with client input quantity but couldn't find a way to achieve my target. I get my price from JSON and when client input a quantity in formControl I want to multiply that **price*quantity** and set to next column.

**Html Code**

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let attItems of filteredProductAttributeItems; let i = index">
                <tr>
                  <td [attr.rowspan]="attItems.ProductAttributeItems.length + 1">{{ attItems.Name }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let att of attItems.ProductAttributeItems">
                  <td>{{ att.MasterProductAttributeItem.Name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ att.PriceAdjustment }}</td>
                  <td style="width: 15%; white-space: nowrap">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Quantity" min="0" />
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
</ng-container>
```

**TS Code**

```
filteredProductAttributeItems: any[] = [];

clickToExpandAttItems(product) {
    this.productService.getProductAttributesItems(product.Id).subscribe(x => {
     Object.assign(this.filteredProductAttributeItems, x);
    });
}
```

[Idea how I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI6op.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your input to Quantity using ngModel two-way binding :

```
<td style="width: 15%; white-space: nowrap">
    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Quantity" min="0" [(ngModel)]="att.Quantity" />
</td>
<td>{{att.Quantity * att.PriceAdjustment}} result</td>
```

Comment: Quantity it's not coming from my API.

Comment: Create your own model containing this logic, and map the data from the API to it. It will be easier to evolve your presentation logic if it's separate from your API data.